# Arrays and overwriting in C++ - can I reuse the same object?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, struct, overwrite

I'm making an array of vectors to save as normals. Because we haven't learned how to do vectors in class yet, I've made a struct which serves just as well:

```
struct vector3
{
    double xcoord;
    double ycoord;
    double zcoord;
};
```

Then, at the beginning of my function, I have this:

```
vector3 vector;
vector3* normalField = new vector3[x];
```

While the function loops through, in each loop, it applies new values to "vector" - at the end of the function, it sets a part of the array to be vector.

```
normalField[x] = vector;
```

The idea is to save memory by not creating a whole bunch of new vectors, and because I have no clue when and where I would be able to use the delete function on that group of vectors. Will this work? Or not? What's the best way of doing this?

The code is very wordy as a whole - I'm writing an algorithm to create a field of normals for procedurally generated terrain. I don't use the built-in vector class because we're not supposed to for some stupid reason. I blame the professor.

Comment: What is the definition of `normalField`? More code would be helpful.

Comment: You don't show enough of your code for us to undertand what you want. Can't you declare e.g. `std::vector<vector3> normalfield;` ... Or what is the declaration of `normalfield`...?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the op is simulating a vector using a struct of doubles, so using a std::vector to have several of them might be a little bit counter-productive, especially if the context of the homework assumes std::vector hasn't been taught yet.

Comment: Assuming `x` is the size of your array your array will only have have positions `0` to `x-1` so `normalField[x] = vector` will go one beyond the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment normalField[x] = vector is going to deep copy the data in vector; you will be creating as many vectors as there are elements in normalField[].

Remember too that in C++ the only difference between a struct and a class is that in a struct data members and functions are public by default, but in a class they are private by default.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be implemented either via array, and creating a new, bigger array when your need for vectors is increased (essentially replicating the behaviour of `std::vector`), or by using a linked list, which could look like this:

```
struct vector3List {
     vector3 v;
     vector3List * next;
};
```

More refined solutions exist, of course, but the choice depends on what you need to do on the vectors.

In case you are not sure how a list is used, here is an example:

```
vector3List * listBegin = new vector3List();
// Setup your vector
listBegin->v.coordX = 6;
// Set the end of the list
listBegin->next = 0;

// You need one more vector
listBegin->next = new vector3List();
// Use some kind of helper pointer to keep track of what vector you are examining
// if you need it
vector3List * iterator = listBegin->next;
// Setup this new second vector
iterator->v.coordX = 5;
// Remember to set the end of the list!
iterator->next = 0;

// Iterate throgh the list
iterator = listBegin;
while ( iterator != 0 ) {
    // Do stuff
    iterator = iterator->next;
}
```

This is, of course, a naive implementation, but you get the idea.